# How to load a folder architecture from a fileserver to a website?

Tags: php, fileserver

I have a folder on a file server, and I would like to update its content regularly. I also want to share the folder with others through a website. So all the files I want to transfer are public, I don't necessarily need encryption. The website is running on an apache server.

I need some PHP code, that can connect to the fileserver, and list all the files in the folder. My problem is, I don't know what file service to use for connection (FTP, FTPS, SFTP, etc.), and how to set this system up. I heard that FTP is not recommended, and I was trying to use SFTP, but it looks quite complicated with PHP.

My fileserver looks like this:

- It has a domain name: [www.mydomainname.com](http://www.mydomainname.com)
- 21, 22 ports are open and forwarded on the router
- I have a password and a username
- And files in the home folder that I want to share

I need a PHP file, that can require the folder structure and the filenames, and make a list of
`<a href=""></a>` tags with reference to the files to download.

I would appreciate any working solution for this problem with a suggested file service and description of the router and file server configurations.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just use Dropbox or Google drive or OneDrive? Seems like a lot of work just to replicate that sort of functionality - which is free unless you have a lot of data

Comment: I would like to load in html files, which I don't want to upload every time to the website when I make them, just put them is a folder and show them automatically. They would be individual interactive documents for teaching purposes.

Comment: Woudn't something like nextcloud suit your needs ?

Comment: Also, I want to upload pdf and other files for my students, and I would like to make an environment where I can place comments and other things next to the files via the website.

Comment: Well, there might be good alternatives out there, but I have my website almost done, I really would like to implement this. I think I have the bigger picture how this should work, but PHP, the fileserver settings and the firewall configuration makes it pretty hard for me to implement it. I met some difficulties in the last days, thats why I'm hoping someone maybe have a complete solution.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need a solution like a CMS, or something like nextcloud or owncloud. I very much doubt you need to build your own application from scratch

Comment: If the only open ports on the machine are 21 and 22 though, your only access options really are FTP or SFTP. Hosting a webserver on there is not going to work, unless you're allowed to make changes to the firewall etc. You _could_ host the frontend application elsewhere and use PHP to pull down the files via SFTP, but that's unlikely to be very efficient or create a good user experience. I wonder if these constraints should have been something you considered _before_ you built 90% of the application, since it seems to be quite an important feature.

Comment: TBH though you'd almost be better to still move the files to something like Dropbox. You can generate public HTTP sharing / download links for all the files, and just put those links into the pages of your website.

Comment: @ADyson I was going to host the frontend application elsewhere and pulling down the files from SFTP originally, and I'm really happy for the comments. I needed some reflections and opinions about my plan, because I was thinking technically it could work, but I don't know how well it could perform. So after your comments now I think it is better to host the webpage from the same place where I upload my files, and I should redirect from the school's webserver to my own server, to make file transfer more efficient.

Comment: Well you could still have the main website on another server, but what you could so is have a webserver running on the fileserver whose only job is to provide HTTP access to the files themselves, so that you can then have hyperlinks to them, as you wanted. It could also have a little bit of PHP on it which returns a list of all the currently available files and URLs to them, in JSON format, so it's quick and easy for the other server to get a list of current files.

Comment: I already have a solution for a "local" php file manager, so that could be implemented easier than moving the files. The downside is that I have to set up an apache webserver, but it still seems easier. I don't want to move my files to cloud services, because I bought my fileserver to have my own.

Comment: P.S. I don't know what operating system your file manager runs, but certainly on most Linux systems it's pretty easy to set up Apache and PHP, usually just a case of downloading some packages, and maybe spending a few minutes configuring if you need something not quite standard. If you're on Windows, it's generally easier to use IIS as the webserver instead.